# Returning String instead of rendering page in wicket

Tags: java, string, url, wicket, mount

I seem to have encountered a problem with my Java app.

So I have this wicket web app where I have an application class which has some mounted urls. I also have an applet in one of these urls. The problem is that this applet sends me post requests to an url specified in the applet parameters when I load the applet and expects a String to come back to the applet. So basically it expects the mounted url to return a string and in wicket I guess it just tries to render the url into a web page and that is not what I want. I guess I have to override a method in the Web Page or something?

Now I am fairly new to wicket so I really have no idea what to do. For example I made this same software with Spring, where I can just map the url with `@RequestMapping("/url")` and use `@ResponseBody` to change the return type to string. This might be a stupid problem but I just can't find my way around it. I've read a lot of wicket documentation and tried to find similar problems but did not find anything.

EDIT: So I have to be able to read the POST request parameters sent by the applet, and send a String back to the applet. I don't know how the applet works so all I know is that it sends a post request with attribtes to a certain address, and it does it multiple times.

Thanks
Samu

Answer (score 3):

As noted in another answer, you can do this using a custom Resource.

But you can also get more or less what you describe in your question by making a subclass of `WebPage` and overriding the `renderPage` method:

```
public class TextPage  extends WebPage {

    @Override
    public final void renderPage() {
        WebResponse response = (WebResponse) getResponse();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.write("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

Of course, as noted in your question, you want also to get the POST parameters sent by the applet and generate the text of the response based on those parameters, rather than just using a constant string ...

You can get these parameters from the request:

```
    Request request = getRequest();
    IRequestParameters postParameters = request.getPostParameters();
    StringValue testParam = postParameters.getParameterValue("test");
    String testParamValue = testParam.toString();
```

All of this is on some level bypassing the usual Wicket way of doing things, as Wicket tries to wrap up access to the request and response so that you never have to deal with them directly, but it may be appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful and solved my problem. I might try that custom resource when I got the time, but overriding the rendering helped! Thank you @Don

Answer (score 1):

You have to mount a custom `Resource`:

```
mountResource("myStringResource", customResourceReference);
```

About custom resources and mounting them you can read here: 
http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/resources.html#resources_7 and the next chapter.

Comment: Do I really have to use Custom resource? I was thinking of putting something like this in the .java class that extends WebPage `WebResponse response = (WebResponse) getRequestCycle().getResponse();
  response.setContentType("text/plain");
  response.write(responseToClient);
  getRequestCycle().setResponse(response);
  response.close();`

Comment: You dont have to but it's in my opinion the way it should be done. If you want to render an page as text and use at least Wicket 6.7.0 you can try: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/core/util/string/ComponentRenderer.html